# example of 2NF and 3NF normalization

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf

I understand the normalization concept, especially the first normal form (1NF), but not 2NF and 3NF.

How does one convert the sample table below to 2NF and 3NF?

```
Prod_id prod_name prod_type  prod_price

1       HP        Laptop     200
2       Adidas    Clothing   100
3       Samsung   Phone      300
3       Samsung   Television 500
```

Comment: *Normalizing requires knowing functional dependencies*. Ie all the cases where a set of columns only ever appears with the same value for another column. So you must give that info! (Column sets that are unique in a table functionally determine all other columns. Primary and alternate keys are unique column sets that don't contain smaller unique column sets. So giving some PKs, alternate keys and/or unique column sets might tell enough about FDs to tell what normal forms a table satisfies and to normalize to tables with higher normal forms.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

example 1: 2FN;
suppose we have this  registry(numStudent,nameStudent ,codeModule) table ;
this  is not in 2NF because of this dependancy : 
  (numStudent,codeModule) is a candidate key for registry table but we have 
    numStudent-> nameStudent so normalize we simply provide registry(numStudent,codeModule)

example 2: 3FN

suppose we have this customer(numCustomer,city,country) tatble ; this is not in 3FN 
because : city->country
so to correct that ,we'll do this one 
R1(numCustomer,city) and R2(city,country)